# There is an error in registering on the site using webdriver Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to register a new account for [this site](https://www.nordstrom.com). However, I cannot register there because of an error or block for ChromeDriver (`selenium` Python).

[image: Webpage view]

I am using this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import random
import string
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["ignore-certificate-errors", "safebrowsing-disable-download-protection", "safebrowsing-disable-auto-update", "disable-client-side-phishing-detection"])
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'chromedriver1.exe')

driver.get('https://www.nordstrom.com/signin?cm_sp=SI_SP_A-_-SI_SP_B-_-SI_SP_C&origin=tab&ReturnURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nordstrom.com%2F')


def email(stringLength=8):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))

email = email(6) + "@gmail.com"

sleep(5)

# email
driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys(email)
sleep(5)

# next
driver.find_element_by_id('account-check-next-button').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

I think the website is blocking `WebDriver`. When I use Chrome in my computer, I don't encounter any problems, but using ChromeDriver, this is the issue I receive.

Comment: Did you try using simple `.click` instead of `.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` ?

Comment: yes it's same problem

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: just show red alert error and not register..

Comment: It seems to not work even in the regular webpage without using Selenium as well.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I made it work manually after clearing cache/cookies for this site. It may be blocking automated requests.

Comment: @ahmaana Check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Open form use:

```
driver.get('https://www.nordstrom.com/signin')
```

Not

```
driver.get('https://www.nordstrom.com/signin?cm_sp=SI_SP_A-_-SI_SP_B-_-SI_SP_C&origin=tab&ReturnURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nordstrom.com%2F')
```

Try to use explicit wait before click:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[alt="next button"]')))
btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[alt="next button"]')
btn.click()
```

It must work because I reproduced your error. The problem is that:

1. You should use `click()` for clicking, not `send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` In your case you click Enter before email is completely input, just before `@` symbol.
2. Your `time.sleep(5)` is not enough. Use explicit wait. Or, in the works case increase your sleep (if you don't case about the speed)

Read here how to use Selenium's wait instead on `time.sleep()`

**Update**:
Clear all cookies, cache, application data for this site and try again. First manually. Looks like it block users after some unsuccessful attempts. Even valid emails.

**UPDATE:**
Unfortunately, Nordstrom is blocking automated requests...
Nordstrom is tracking all customers actions, so it's unlikely to be used for testing. I would suggest to try other sites to save your time.
[image]

Comment: yes iam trying the code but the problem not solve, i think the website block the driver selenuim

Comment: 1. Do not copy other people answer as it is yours. 2 Still the same error?

Comment: Did you understand what the problem is? You are trying to click the button before text input is complete.

Comment: Look at the code in my answer below, I fill in the email field then wait 30 seconds then click the Next button

Comment: I have tried everything that I mentioned in the mod, but the same problem prevents me from manual recording too

and try driver.delete_all_cookies()
same error

Comment: So, you have no success in manual input right?

Comment: this is error show in request when i try register
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://secure.nordstrom.com/" on this server.
Reference�

Comment: when iam using chrome in my windows no any error 
but in chrome selenuim is error

Comment: Check here for all options you can try to pass https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/. I am not completely sure which is better to try to use in this case.

Comment: If nobody answers, I'll try to check what can be done with it tomorrow.

Comment: I have tried all the ways, I have not decided the solution yet !!
Did you try the site from your side?